# Apache Superset : Report Schedule execution failed when generating a csv

Tags: charts, report, dashboard, apache-superset

Herewith error image : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5FZv.png)

When generating alerts and reports charts as an csv, the reports cannot be sent because there's error "Report Schedule execution failed when generating a csv." also if I set as png the error is "Failed taking a screenshot local variable 'element' referenced before assignment"

But when I'm using dashboard as an attachment, the email can be sent but the panel inside the dashboard is not appear.

I'm using superset version 2.0.0.

Can you help me guys ?